# Unknown location in SFTP using JSCH

Tags: java, jsch, oracle-data-integrator

I have problem with short script JSCH which I'm using ind Oracle Data Integrator.
I want to send file from directory to server SFTP.
My code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

JSch ssh = new JSch();
Session session = ssh.getSession("pas", "host", 22);

session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(
        "PreferredAuthentications", 
        "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
session.setPassword("pass");

session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();

ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

sftp.put("C:\Tools\tmp.html", "/var/temp/temp.html");

channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

I get error:

```
ODI-1590: The execution of the script failed. 
Caused By: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: BeanShell script error: Sourced file:
inline evaluation of: ``
import oracle.odi.km.exception.OdiKMException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
J . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 23, column 19. 
Encountered: "W" (87), after : "\"C:\\": <at unknown location>
BSF info: upload file at line: 0 column: columnNo
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please try sftp.put("C:/Tools/tmp.html", "/var/temp/temp.html");

Comment: Try `sftp.put("C:\\Tools\\tmp.html", "/var/temp/temp.html");`

Comment: @deHaar - your solution has helped! Thanks! Can you explain why I muust use '\\' instead '\' or can you give me link to documentatio which describe this?

Comment: Oracle Data Integrator also has a built-in sFTP tool that you can use in a package or a procedure without having to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the backslashes in your local path `String`:

```
sftp.put("C:\\Tools\\tmp.html", "/var/temp/temp.html");
```

That's because a backslash itself escapes the next character and if you put single backslashes in `"C:\Tools\tmp.html"`, the result would be (but isn't) something like `"C:oolsmp.html"`, which is unlikely to be considered a valid path.

In my IDE (eclipse), a `String` with single backslashes is considered a compilation error, the code doesn't even compile.

The error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```